# $G=(V,E)$, edges can be partitioned into 4 parts, $E=E_1 \cup E_2 \cup E_3\cup E_4 $ where $(V,E_{i})$ is a tree.Prove that $\chi(G) \leq 8$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, coloring

I tried on this problem in a few ways.

1. There exists at least $1$ vertex of degree $ \le 7 $. But this
   doesn't mean it is a maximal degree and doesn't seem to help me a
   lot.
2. Each tree can be colored in $2$ colors, and there are $4$ trees so
   $2\times4=8$ may leads to the result? I'm not sure of this approach.

A little bit of hint would also help a lot. Thank you.

Comment: Your second way looks good.

Comment: @GerryMyerson What's your idea for using the second way?

Comment: @bof |E1|=|E2|=|E3|=|E4|=|V|-1 and this leads to average of degree=8-(8/|V|)$\leq$ 7 and this implies the existence of the vertex of degree $\leq$ 7. I'm thinking about the induction either, like after deleting this vertex each component will satisfy the conditions. But it seems like deleting this vertex destroys one condition on components that each subgraph $(V,E_{i}) is a tree and i'm actullay stuck in here.

Comment: So it works for forests as well as trees? So maybe you can use this to prove the more general statement, if $G$ is decomposable into $4$ forests, then $\chi(G)\le8$?

Comment: An acyclic graph on $n$ vertices has $\le n-1$ edges, why do they have to be trees?

Comment: @bof Great. I agree. But how come more general statement is easier to be proved? I doubt i missed out on something.

Comment: It is quite usual and to be expected that a "more general statement is easier" to prove, especially in inductive proofs.

Comment: @GerryMyerson You are aware that, with "tree" replaced by "bipartite graph", the best possible upper bound would be $\chi(G)\le2^4=16$? So what do you mean by the "second way"?

Comment: @bof never mind, I think I underestimated the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your first idea is on the right track. If you are interested, the `relevant concept' in this problem is that of [Degeneracy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degeneracy_(graph_theory)).

First hint (hover your mouse over it):

> Consider the edges to be divided into 4 *forests*, rather than trees, just for simplicity. Now note that if $H$ is *any subgraph* of $G$, then $E(H)$ can still be divided into at most 4 forests. In particular, you can pull off a vertex $u$ of degree 7 or less, and $G-u$ will still have some vertex $v$ of degree 7 or less.

Second hint:

> Pulling the vertices of degree at most 7 off one by one like this gives you a simple algorithm to 8-colour the graph.

Explicit description:

> The graph $G$ contains some vertex with degree at most 7. Call this vertex $v_n$. The edges of subgraph $G-\{v_n\}$ can also be partitioned into 4 forests, so $G-\{v_n\}$ has a vertex of degree at most 7. Call this vertex $v_{n-1}$. Repeat this procedure of labeling and removing vertices until you reach $v_1$ and have exhausted the vertex set. Notice that, by the way we have labelled the vertices, that any vertex $v_j$ is adjacent to at most 7 vertices $v_i$, where $i<j$ (so $v_j$ has 7 or fewer neighbours that come before it in the list $v_1, v_2, \dots, v_j, \dots, v_n$). We colour the vertices with 8 colours, starting with $v_1$ and ending with $v_n$, as follows: Color the first 7 vertices with colours 1, 2, $\dots$, 7. Now for each vertex $v_j$ where $j > 7$, $v_j$ has at most 7 neighbors that have already been coloured. Thus, even in the worst case that every earlier neighbor has a different colour, $v_j$ can be given one of the 8 colours.